# Клиент Rest api на android

Tags: android, rest

Какими средствами лучше (и проще) организовать взаимодействие с rest сервисом на android?
Формат данных json. Запросов будет довольно много. Кэширование пока не нужно, но в будущем может понадобиться.
Изобретать свой велосипед не охота.
Пока присматриваюсь к библиотеке RoboSpice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Почти стандарт: [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

> A type-safe REST client for Android and Java

Я использую [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

> A Callback-Based Http Client Library for Android

Comment: Тоже сейчас в проекте использую Async по Вашей ссылке. Среди плюсов могу отметить, что это одна из немногих библиотек, которая позволила добавлять параметры в DELETE запрос. Стандартом это не предусмотрено, но в моём случае было архиважно.

Comment: Подскажите, есть ли в AsyncHttpClient поддержка кэширования?

Answer (score 1):

[Spring for Android](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/)

> Spring for Android is an extension of the Spring Framework that aims to simplify the development of native Android applications.